# "ScrollView can only host 1 child" in 2 fragments with only 1 child?

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have 2 fragments, each with a ScrollView, and 1 ConstraintLayout inside. The ContraintLayout contains multiple children inside, but the ScrollViews only have 1 child. When I go to fragment 1, I recieve no error. I go to fragment 2, all good. When I return to fragment 1 however, I get the following error:

```
2020-03-20 22:56:20.491 7887-7887/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.starenkysoftware.vanshapp, PID: 7887
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
        at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:266)
        at com.google.android.material.snackbar.BaseTransientBottomBar.showView(BaseTransientBottomBar.java:719)
        at com.google.android.material.snackbar.BaseTransientBottomBar$1.handleMessage(BaseTransientBottomBar.java:243)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I do not understand how this is possible, as I do not add anything else within the layout while switching

EDIT: Added code

Fragment 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipient_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Beneficiary"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/recipient_splitter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recipient_header"/>

    <!-- Recipient Name Fields -->

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/recipient_first_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recipient_splitter"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/recipient_middle_name"
    android:hint="First Name">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/first_name_field"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/recipient_middle_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recipient_splitter"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/recipient_first_name"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/recipient_last_name"
                android:hint="Middle Name">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/middle_name_field"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/recipient_last_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recipient_first_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recipient_first_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/recipient_middle_name"
        android:hint="Last Name">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/last_name_field"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Recipient Location Field -->

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/recipient_state"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recipient_first_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/recipient_city"
        android:hint="Province">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/state_field"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/recipient_city"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recipient_state"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recipient_state"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/recipient_state"
        android:hint="City">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/city_field"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Phone Number -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_number_layout"
        app:prefixText=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recipient_state"
        android:hint="Phone Number">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_number_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Transger Info Section -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transfer_info_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Transfer Info"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/phone_number_layout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/transfer_info_splitter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/transfer_info_header"/>

    <!-- SOF (Source of Fund -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/sof_layout"
        app:prefixText=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/transfer_info_splitter"
        android:hint="Source of Fund">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/sof_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <!-- Type of Transfer Dropdown -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:id="@+id/type_of_transfer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="Type"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sof_layout">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/type_of_transfer_dropdown"
            android:editable="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/btb_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/type_of_transfer_layout">

            <!-- Bank Name -->
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/bank_name_layout"
                app:prefixText=""
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:hint="Bank Name">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/bank_name_field"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <!-- Phone Number -->
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/bank_account_number_layout"
                app:prefixText=""
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bank_name_layout"
                android:hint="Bank Account Number">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/bank_account_number_field"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <!-- Currency Selector -->
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:id="@+id/currency_selector_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/amount_layout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/amount_layout"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/currency_dropdown"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Amount Field -->


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/amount_layout"
        app:prefixText=""
        app:suffixText="CAD"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btb_info"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/currency_selector_layout"
        android:hint="Amount">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/amount_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currency_rate_small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/photo_checkbox"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/amount_layout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/amount_layout" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Send"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amount_layout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/photo_button"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Photo Verification"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amount_layout"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/photo_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/photo_button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/photo_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/photo_button"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/submit_button"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/previous_transfer_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Previous 5 Transfers"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView1"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/previous_transfer_title">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/transfer_card_1_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Exchange Rate"
            android:textColor="#878787"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView2"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialCardView1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/transfer_card_2_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Exchange Rate"
            android:textColor="#878787"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView3"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialCardView2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/transfer_card_3_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Exchange Rate"
            android:textColor="#878787"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView4"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialCardView3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/transfer_card_4_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Exchange Rate"
            android:textColor="#878787"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView5"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialCardView4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/transfer_card_5_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Exchange Rate"
            android:textColor="#878787"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @AndreyStarenky, while switching between fragments, do you add any new view to your ScrollView?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh nope, I'm 99% sure I don't add anything. There may have been something super small I missed, I'll let you know if I find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had snackbars that attatched to items. They worked perfectly under some circumstances, but for some reason not always. I think this may have something to do with how Fragments are created and destroyed upon exit.

I replaced my snackbars with toasts, and it fixed the issue, although the appearance has been worsened.